# User Events - eg Check Box

Tags: c#

Is there a way the CheckedChanged event (or any other C# event) to be declared as User event? The problem is that if the property Checked is changed by code the Event is called and this is a thing that I would not want (for example in MFC the events are user events as opposed to property events). I by pass it with boolean flags and this is a little bit awkward in 2011!

Comment: If you care where the change came from there's a big chance you are doing something wrong. Why does it matter if the check box is set from code?

Comment: @Jon - you got a very good point. Although in rare cases it can be helpful to know if the event is user generated vs. code-generated most of the time it should be abstracted away..

Comment: @Jon I can imagine a few cases when that would be useful. For example, if you want to write to log when the user checks a box, or if you want to show a message box when the user ticks the check box, but don't need it when you call from code. Sure, you could add an underlying variable, kind of like another layer, to get an architecture that better supports that, but maybe that's over-engineering a simple exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unsubcribe the event. After you change the value you can subscribe again.

```
this.checkBox1.CheckedChanged -= new EventHandler(checkBox1_CheckedChanged);
this.checkBox1.Checked = true; // will not firing the CheckedChanged  event 
this.checkBox1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(checkBox1_CheckedChanged);
```

alternativly you can set a variable to bypass like this

```
bool isUser = true;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    isUser = false;
    this.checkBox1.Checked = true;
    isUser = true;
}

void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!isUser) // check if the change has fired by user
        return;

    // ... 
}
```

both will work

**hope this helps.**

Comment: It seems promising, thanks I ll look at it. This thw was I did, with variales. The unsubscribe is more clear becahse one event interacts theother but it goes the other way around and it gets confusing.

Comment: It feels awkward to write `this.checkBox1.CheckedChanged -= new EventHandler(checkBox1_CheckedChanged);` I mean, isn't `new EventHandler(checkBox1_CheckedChanged)` a new object? If yes, then that new object can't already exist in the `CheckedChanged` collection. Although I'll readily believe you on your word that this code works as you imply it does.

Answer (score 1):

C# definitely does not support "user events". It only supports one type of events which are specified using the keyword event (they are essentially just *controlled* delegate references) . If you'd like to learn a bit more about how C# treats events have a look at [Jon Skeet's excellent treatment of the subject here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx).

Now, what you're comparing is not really apples to apples. MFC is a framework. C# is a language. So, as far as frameworks go, it depends on the framework. In your example, it looks like you're referring to WinForms. If that's so - again, the answer is unfortunately no: WinForms does not support "user events" as you described them.